# Allow a DynamoDB User to modify a subset of documents

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How can I create a policy in DynamoDB, which allows the corresponding IAM users to modify just a **subset of the documents** in a table?

For example, let's say there is an attribute `published`,
and I want this IAM user to perform PutItem and UpdateItem
on documents which have `published: false`.

Comment: The specific feature you are looking for is called fine grained access control (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html) but I'm not sure what the specific policy would look like based on the available examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use DynamoDB Fine-Grained Access Control on the hash key value. You could save an item with "draft" pre-pended to the hash-key value and use the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:REGION:ACCOUNT_NUMBER:table/TABLE_NAME"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                   "dynamodb:LeadingKeys":  ["draft*"],
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Adapted from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html

Comment: That's just brilliant.  Thanks!